# how to insert a record into mysql(jdbc) in java using rmi?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc, rmi

I am making a project in Java using swings,JDBC and I want to use RMI to insert records into my MySQL database. Everything is working fine until I use RMI.

When I use RMI everything works but my database table doesn't reflect a new entry being made.

How can this be done?

here is my remote implementation code

```
    package server;

import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.*;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class myremote_imp extends UnicastRemoteObject implements myremote{

    String URL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project";
    String user="root";
    String pass="root";

    public myremote_imp()throws RemoteException
    {}

    public void putdata(String s6,String s7,String s8,String s1,String s2,String s3,String s4,String s5,String User,String Pass,String P_name,String P_price)
    {
        try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection C=DriverManager.getConnection(URL,user,pass);
            System.out.println("connection Established");
            PreparedStatement S=C.prepareStatement("insert into customers values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            S.setString(1,s6);
            S.setString(2,s7);
            S.setString(3,s8); 
            S.setString(4,s1);
            S.setString(5,s2);
            S.setString(6,s3);
            S.setString(7,s4);
            S.setString(8,s5);
            S.setString(9,User);
            S.setString(10,Pass);
            S.setString(11,P_name);
            S.setString(12,P_price);
            //System.out.println(s6+s7+s8+s1+s2+s3+s4);just to check if values are being passed by the remote correctly which is true
        }
        catch(Exception E)
        {
            System.out.println(E);
        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] Args) throws RemoteException
    {
        try
        {
            Registry Rg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(6199);
            myremote mr = new myremote_imp();
            Rg.rebind("remotedata",mr);

        }
        catch(Exception E)
        {
            System.out.println(E);
        }
    }

}
```

output:

```
connection is establised
```

but changes are not reflected in the database.

Comment: Typo, the OP forgot to run a command, `executeUpdate()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but changes are not reflected in the database.

You forgot to call [executeUpdate()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate(java.lang.String)) at the end of `putdata()` method.

```
.......................
S.setString(12,P_price);
S.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: thank you so much . I always forget to use executeupdate().